# Collection with collection to csv, new row for each nested collection

Tags: c#, ienumerable, csvhelper

I have query result data that is a collection of student data. Each student collection has an associated contact collection.

Some students have no contacts, some have several.

I need 2 csv's from this student collection. One that is students only, and the one I'm having trouble with: a csv with a row for each student
and their associated contact. If Bobby has no contacts then he has 1 row. If Suezy has 3 contacts, then 3 rows of her information
with the contact data included in the row.

I'm trying to use CsvHelper to do this, but I'm not geting the result I expectd. See Josh Close's answer [here](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/389).

I'm using csv's for my sample data, one student with 2 contacts, 2 students with one contact each. And 1 student with no contacts.

Students:

```
StudentSisId    Name
111111          Betty
222222          Veronica
333333          Jughead
444444          Archie
```

Contacts:

```
StudentSisId    Relationship
111111          Mother
111111          Father
222222          Mother
444444          Father
```

My code:
Classes:

```
public class Student
{
    public string StudentSisId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }

}

public class Contact
{
    public string StudentSisId { get; set; }
    public string Relationship { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping:

```
    public sealed class StudentClassMap : ClassMap<Student>
    {
        public StudentClassMap()
        {
            Map(m => m.StudentSisId);
            Map(m => m.Name);
            Map(m => m.Contacts).Index(2);
        }
    }

    public sealed class ContactClassMap : ClassMap<Contact>
    {
        public ContactClassMap()
        {
            Map(m => m.StudentSisId).Index(1);
            Map(m => m.Relationship).Index(2);
        }
    }
```

The code:

```
    private static void StudentsWithContacts()
    {
        var csvReader = new ReadCsvFile();

        List<Student> students = csvReader.GetDataCollection<Student>(@"c:\temp\studentsWithoutContacts.csv");
        List<Contact> contacts = csvReader.GetDataCollection<Contact>(@"c:\temp\contacts.csv");

        foreach (var student in students)
        {
            if (contacts.Any(x => x.StudentSisId == student.StudentSisId))
            {
                var studentContacts = contacts.Where(x => x.StudentSisId == student.StudentSisId).ToList();
                student.Contacts = new List<Contact>();
                student.Contacts.AddRange(studentContacts);
            }
        }

        using (var textWriter = File.CreateText(@"c:\temp\studentsWithContacts.csv"))
        using (var writer = new CsvWriter(textWriter))
        {
            writer.WriteHeader<Student>();
            writer.WriteRecords(students);
        }
     }
```

This gives results (why is Betty in the header?):

StudentSisId    Name    111111  Betty
222222          Veronica
333333          Jughead
444444          Archie

I'm expecting:

```
StudentSisId        Name        Relationship
111111              Betty       Mother
111111              Betty       Father
222222              Veronica    Mother
333333              Jughead 
444444              Archie      Father
```

Am I on the right track, or did i misunderstand the tool?  This sample is CsvHelper 3.2. I can update if necessary.

Comment: Sounds like you have a N:M relationship. Every student can have every other student as a contact. Usually this is solved via a Intermediate table. And that intermediate table could be stored to a CSV, same as with any other tables.

Comment: No, students are students, and contacts are parents. Each parent has a relationship. The actual data is much larger, including contact info etc. This is greatly simplified. The purpose of the app is to consolidate the student/parent info and export it via SFTP to a vendor.

Comment: That it is a N:M between Student and Parent rather Student:Student does not change that you got a N:M. And those have to be resolved into two 1:N using a intermediate table (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.ddi.doc/ids_ddi_186.htm). Such a table can be presresented with CSV same as any other.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite familiar with csvhelper to handle your needs. But with [Cinchoo ETL](https://github.com/Cinchoo/ChoETL) / Linq, you can perform the file merge as below.

```
string csv1 = @"StudentSisId,Name
111111,Betty
222222,Veronica
333333,Jughead
444444,Archie";

string csv2 = @"StudentSisId,Relationship
111111,Mother
111111,Father
222222,Mother
444444,Father
";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
using (var p1 = ChoCSVReader.LoadText(csv1)
    .WithFirstLineHeader()
    )
{
    using (var p2 = ChoCSVReader.LoadText(csv2)
        .WithFirstLineHeader()
        )
    {
        var j1 = from r1 in p1
                    join r2 in p2
                    on r1.StudentSisId equals r2.StudentSisId into p22
                    from r22 in p22.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new { StudentSisId = r1.StudentSisId, Name = r1.Name, Relationship = r22 != null ? r22.Relationship : null };

        using (var w = new ChoCSVWriter(sb)
            .WithFirstLineHeader()
            )
            w.Write(j1);
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

**Output:**

```
StudentSisId,Name,Relationship
111111,Betty,Mother
111111,Betty,Father
222222,Veronica,Mother
333333,Jughead,
444444,Archie,Father
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Why, thank you. I don't think I can use ChoCSVReader in my project, as CsvHelper is our standard. I can use the Linq you suggested. I like the fact that the linq is more readable than a call to a package anyway. I'll add an upvote, and mark as the answer if no one comes up with the CsvHelper solution.